# Using closure to keep track of the state of previous function call

Tags: javascript

I came across this question during an interview and I couldn't figure it out.

The expected output is:

1

2

3

4

**the code:**

```
for(var i =0; i< 4; i++){
    console.log(next());
}
```

The question is to implement function `next()`;
The interviewer gave me the answer in the end but I cant remember it. I dont know how next() can figure out the earlier state of the previous next() call;
I remember the solution is to return a function, and uses closure but how does that help me keep track of the counter when next() get called again.

He also said u don't have to care about what i is for each iteration

Comment: Well, since `i` is the looping variable, why don't you start by actually trying to write `next()` that gets passed `i` from the loop? Or, since `next` will be called 4 times, why not have `next` use its own variable? I think you are overthinking this.

Comment: If `i` is a global variable, it should be trivial. If not, make your own local variable that `next` closes over that will be incremented (and returned) on each call.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question you were given, given that just `console.log(i+1)` (with appropriate whitespace added) does this trivially. There must be some further conditions or context which necessitate using closures. (I love closures, but there's no point using one if there is a trivial alternative solution!)

Comment: Also, the environment where this code lives and where `next` is defined in relation to it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var next = (function () {
  var num = 0;
  
  return function() {
    num += 1;
    return num
  }
})()

for(var i =0; i< 4; i++){
    console.log(next());
}
```

[closure magic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Comment: We tend not to answer questions that don't make an attempt. Also, when we do answer, we should explain what we're doing.